# FileZilla Server Exclude File

Tags: ftp, filezilla, transfer

I've setup a user (using the FileZilla Server) to show files in a specific folder (read-only).

**How can I make a specific file in that folder non-readable?**

Comment: Remove the read permission from the file.

Comment: How do I go about editing the permissions? When I try doing so with a higher privileged FTP account, I get given "Command not implemented for that parameter". It is a Windows server by the way.

Comment: [How do I set "access permissions" for a file or folder on my web server?](http://www.geckotribe.com/help/access-permissions.php)